# Issue with Texture Display in Cloned Project from GitHub Repository

Tags: ros, gazebo

I cloned the project from GitHub repository ([line_follower_pkg](https://github.com/DougUOW)), and I'm encountering an issue with the texture on the ground not displaying correctly. Despite following the right steps, the texture fails to appear as intended. I tried if it was a path problem, but if the material is not found, gazebo just doesnt open and crashes.

Gazebo Version: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations I use the last one

SO: Windows 10
I dont know how to see the ros version

I open my miniforge3 then I go in my env with mamba activate ros_env and then I do the setup.bat in devel and run the launch file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.